# Permutations with multiple list and Conditions

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I want to generate list of all possible Strings of each 5 character 
permutation of two list

```
List 1: [A-Z] all caps Alphabets
List 2: [0-9] Digits
```

**conditions of string**

1. Each string must contain min. of 1 digit and min. of 1 Alphabet
2. Each string must not contain more than 3 of same (Digit/Alphabet)

**Example Outputs:**

```
B9B61
6F084
7C9DA
9ECF9
E7ACF
```

i tried this but i know i could not apply conditions so far, pretty confused right now
kindly help

```
from itertools import permutations 

perm = [''.join(p) for p in permutations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', 5)] 

for i in list(perm): 
    with open("list.txt", "a+") as file:
        file.write(i)
        file.write("\n")
```

Comment: "Each string must not contain more than 3 of same (Digit/Alphabet)" does that mean it can't contain more than 3 of the same character ("AAAA" not allowed) or that it can't contain more than 3 digits or letters? ("ABCD" and "1234" not allowed)

Comment: Example 7A77B, AAA5B, AAAA9 all here are invalid

Comment: @lain it can not contain of same Character

Comment: The first 2 examples only have 3 repeated chars not more?

Comment: A String can contain 2 Repeated Character but not 3

Answer (score 2):

The following will print out all 5 char combinations of all uppercase letters and digits with no more than 3 of any char or digit.

```
import string
import itertools
possible_combinations = itertools.permutations(string.ascii_uppercase * 3 + string.digits * 3, 5)
for possible_str in (''.join(chars) for chars in possible_combinations):
    if possible_str.isnumeric() or possible_str.isalpha():
        continue
    else:
       print(possible_str)
```

To get all combinations of letters and digits with no more than 3 repeated first we look at `itertools.permutations`. Given an iterable of chars (a string) it will return all combinations of those chars for the given length

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations('ABC', 3)]
['ABC', 'ACB', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'CAB', 'CBA']
```

If we pass 2 of each char, permutations will return all combinations with up to 2 of every char

```
>>> [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations('AABBCC', 3)]
['AAB', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'AAB', 'AAB', 'AAC', 'AAC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ABA', 'ABB', 'ABC', 'ABC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'ACA', 'ACB', 'ACB', 'ACC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BAC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BAC', 'BBA', 'BBA', 'BBC', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'BCA', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BAC', 'BAA', 'BAB', 'BAC', 'BAC', 'BBA', 'BBA', 'BBC', 'BBC', 'BCA', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'BCA', 'BCA', 'BCB', 'BCC', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CBA', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CBA', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CCA', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCB', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CAA', 'CAB', 'CAB', 'CAC', 'CBA', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CBA', 'CBA', 'CBB', 'CBC', 'CCA', 'CCA', 'CCB', 'CCB']
```

The same holds true if we increase the number of chars and how many we repeat them by. So we have `string.ascii_uppercase * 3 + string.digits * 3` which returns a string with all uppercase letters repeated 3 times and all digits repeated 3 times

The last thing to do it filter out strings with no digits or letters in them. string.isnumeric() returns true if all chars are digits and string.isalpha() returns true if all chars are letters

Comment: Thank you @iain <3 seems perfect! and thank you for wonderful explanation sir

Comment: string are getting repeated in the list :/

Answer (score 1):

You can go with your `permutations` by applying some checks:

```
from itertools import permutations
from collections import Counter

for i in permutations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789', 5):
    combo = "".join(i)
    result = Counter(i)
    if any(s>=3 for s in result.values()) \
            or sum(c.isdigit() for c in i)<1 \
            or sum(c.isalpha() for c in i)<1:
        continue
    print (combo)
```

Comment: Thank you sir but, following output is missing in it 
`AB455(Missing)
AAB23 (Missing)`

Comment: @AyushAgarwal If you are looking for elements to be repeatable, you shouldn't use `permutations` at all. You should use [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 

output = [] #always initiate as empty

alphanum = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

while len(output) < 5:#5 is max

    output.append(random.choice(alphanum)) #pick random from list

    counter_i = counter_s = 0 #counter for integers and characters

    for element in output:

        if isinstance(element,int): 

            counter_i +=1

        elif isinstance(element,str):

            counter_s +=1

        if (counter_i > 3 or counter_s >3) : #max 3  for numbers or strings

            output.pop() #remove from list if it exceeds the limits


print(output)       
['M', 'Z', 4, 'B', 9]

result = '' 
for l in output:
    result +=str(l)

print(result)
MZ4B9
```

Comment: sir, its generating only 1 result, im looking list of all possible results

Comment: Excuse me, it was not clear to me that it was your intention. Maybe you should rephrase your question.

Comment: im sorry, i will rephrase the question again thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you can try this function. it returns unique and least one alphabet and one digit.

```
import random 

alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ" 
digits = "0123456789"

def generate_code(length):
    alp_len = random.randint(1,length-1)
    dig_len = length-alp_len

    selected = list(random.sample(alphabets,alp_len))
    selected.extend (random.sample(digits,dig_len))

    random.shuffle ( selected ) 

    return ''.join(selected) 


print (generate_code(5))
```

> random.sample(population, k)
>
> Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence. Used for random sampling without replacement.

Comment: sir, its generating only 1 result, im looking list of all possible results